# validates_uniqueness custom handling ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validates-uniqueness-of

I would like load the particular record if it fails the validates_uniqueness constraint.

I have id (primary key) and title in my model. If the user enters a title which is already present if want to search for the record with the title and load that record instead of throwing the error.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `before_validation` callback to check validity yourself, and when it fails, trigger the behavior you're looking for. So, one way to do it would be to write code in `before_validation`, and in there you could do a simple `.valid?` call, or manually run the validation for uniqueness by itself. When validation fails, you can stop the callback chain, and trigger custom behavior.

`before_validation` is one of the many [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) available to you.

Another, more common way to do it would be, in your controller, instead of just saving you can basically wrap the `.save` call in an if statement, because `.save` returns `false` if validation fails. You can use this as a way to redirect to an alternate action, in the situation you describe.

```
@new_record = ThingImSaving.new(params[:thing_im_saving]
if @new_record.save
  ...validation has passed, continue the normal path
else
  ...validation has failed, do something else.
end
```